# Infinispan server cache change encoding 'application/x-jboss-marshalling' to 'application/x-protostream'

Tags: caching, marshalling, infinispan, hot-rod

I am currently configured my cache container in JBoss 7.4 standalone.xml, and the ISPN remote server running on localhost. Everything was fine until it throws the error:

**ISPN000492: Cannot find transcoder between 'application/x-jboss-marshalling' to 'application/x-protostream'**

standalone.xml:

```
         <remote-cache-container name="remoteContainer" default-remote-cluster="data-grid-cluster">
            <property name="infinispan.client.hotrod.sasl_mechanism">SCRAM-SHA-512</property>
            <property name="infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_realm">default</property>
            <property name="infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_username">admin</property>
            <property name="infinispan.client.hotrod.auth_password">12345</property>
            <property name="infinispan.client.hotrod.client_intelligence">BASIC</property>
            <remote-clusters>
                <remote-cluster name="data-grid-cluster" socket-bindings="ispn1 ispn2"/>
            </remote-clusters>
        </remote-cache-container>
```

ISPN Cache configuration:

{
"distributed-cache": {
"mode": "SYNC",
"owners": 2,
"encoding": {
"key": {
"media-type": "application/x-protostream"
},
"value": {
"media-type": "application/x-protostream"
}
},
"expiration": {
"lifespan": 5000,
"max-idle": 1000
},
"statistics": true
}
}

Note: I don't want to change the cache encoding because the infinispan web console stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying the client cache has media type `application/x-jboss-marshalling`, and you want `application/x-protostream` instead.

Looking at the WildFly 23.x code, it will use `ProtoStreamMarshaller` (and media type `application/x-protostream`) iff the application has a `SerializationContextInitializer` implementation in its classpath.

Even if you only store strings and primitives in the cache, you still have to write an interface and annotate it with `@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder` for `RemoteCacheContainerConfigurationServiceConfigurator` to choose `ProtoStreamMarshaller`.

In WildFly 24.x the auto-detection mechanism changes, and `ProtoStreamMarshaller` is picked if the modules attribute includes `org.wildfly.clustering.web.hotrod`, so `<remote-cache-container modules="org.wildfly.clustering.web.hotrod">` might also work on 23.x.

In Wildfly 24.x you can always set `<remote-cache-container marshaller="PROTOSTREAM">` to choose `ProtoStreamMarshaller` manually.

Comment: Thanks for response! u have an example of implement an interface of @AutoProtoSchemaBuilder?

Comment: See https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/encoding/encoding.html#annotating-autoprotoschemabuilder_marshalling

Comment: In my case only I store a simple String on cache not a Object, how i can do that? ty

Comment: IIRC you can write an interface and annotate it with `@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder` even if you don't have any custom classes and you leave the `includeClasses` empty. But it does complicate your life a bit because you have to make sure the annotation processor runs and generates the service loader file in `META-INF/services`. I'd much rather upgrade to WildFly 24+, which doesn't need this any more because it lets you select the marshaller directly.

Comment: Thank you, actually I use JBoss EAP 7.4. You recommend me upgrade to WilfFly 24+? What is Jboss's version equivalent? 
What is true is that the cache works fine, and the only disadvantage is the web console of the server that does not show the entries but the rest works fine!

Comment: No, I wouldn't recommend moving from EAP to WildFly just for this... I'd say instead follow the steps in the link I posted and let the ProtoStream annotation processor create a dummy SerializationContextInitializer, or even write a class implementing SerializationContextInitializer to do nothing yourself and put a reference to it in `META-INF/services` manually if you'd rather avoid the dependency. I forgot to mention earlier, but if you're only using strings then `text/plain` is also an option, and IIRC the web console also works with `text/plain`.

Comment: Thank for response! My app runs on EAP 7.4 and I tried to configure the cache with encode "text/plain" but i got the following error when i put an entry:
ISPN004005: Error received from the server: org.infinispan.commons.dataconversion.EncodingException: ISPN000495: JBossMarshallingTranscoder encountered error transcoding content
java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 1

Comment: {
  "distributed-cache": {
    "mode": "SYNC",
    "owners": 2,
    "encoding": {
      "key": {
        "media-type": "text/plain"
      },
      "value": {
        "media-type": "text/plain"
      }
    },
    "expiration": {
      "lifespan": 5000,
      "max-idle": 1000
    },
    "statistics": true
  }
}

Comment: Sorry, I read "I don't want to change the cache encoding" in your question and I assumed you can change the encoding in the client configuration! Looking at the code I'm not sure the RemoteCacheContainer abstraction in WildFly/EAP is meant to support the full range of marshallers/encodings that the underlying Infinispan cache container supports.

Comment: Maybe there are no solution for this. In jboss eap 7.4 is not possible change the encoding jboss-marshaller.

Comment: Except for protostream :) You *can* change the marshaller to protostream if you add an implementation of `SerializationContextInitializer` to your application, it's just a bit annoying to have to write/generate that implementation when you only need strings.